# Is it common practice to hold a repository globally?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, repository

In repository examples, I see the repository instantiated when the Session opens, which seems as if it is around for the entire Session.  In controller actions, the data layer is then accessed through calls to the repository.  Is this common practice? Wouldn't it make more sense to be instantiating the repository in an on need basis per action request?

Edit: A more exact scenario.

```
public class myController : Controller {
  IMyRepository myRepository;

  public myController(IMyRepository repositoryParam){
    myRepository = repositoryParam;
  }

  public ActionResult someAction(){
    MyClass myClass = myRepository.RepositoryAction();
  }
}
```

In this scenario, myRepository is global to myController (note: this is based off an example from Steven Sanderson).  I have seen it also defined for all controllers to access, but this is a simple, exact, example.  In this example, why would the repository be used globally instead of on a per use basis?

Comment: A repository is quite a broad notion. You will have to define your exact scenario in a much more specific manner in order to make some sense out of your question.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Edited with a more exact scenario.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - I'm assuming he is referring to a repository as is shown in many ASP.NET MVC examples (using the repository pattern to access the data layer). Typically in those examples, the concrete repository object is accessing a database via EF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, Travis, you should read up a bit on the [Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx). This pattern is used to provide a number of advantages, including:

- It centralizes the data logic or Web service access logic.
- It provides a substitution point for the unit tests.
- It provides a flexible architecture that can be adapted as the overall design of the application evolves.

As to your question: "Is this a common practice?" the answer is, "It should be." but, unfortunately, I don't see it as much as I would prefer.

Now, in your example, you show the repository being created within the context of your controller class. (Please note that this is NOT the same thing as an object being made "global" as you put it. Global means that the object is accessible from any scope. Read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) at Wikipedia.)

In any case, one of the advantages is that the repository allows you to change between how you are accessing your data (or even where your data is being accessed) by using the correct, concrete version of the repository. So, you may have:

- IRepository - Your interface which the concrete repositories implement.
- DatabaseRepository - Accesses your data in a database.
- FlatFileRepository - Access your data out of a flat file.
- etc.

If you wish to switch to other data sources, it is a simple as swapping out the concrete implementation in your controller. (Please note, there are more advanced and flexible ways of doing this through [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), but that is out of scope of this question, although it does/can play heavily in the repository pattern.)

In any case, say your project team decides "Hey, we're going to switch from storing all our data in flat files to using a database." Well, if you have scattered the instantiations of that specific repository throughout your code, you now have a lot of different areas to fix and update, somewhat negating the advantages of the repository pattern. However, by declaring a member repository of your controller, you just switch from a FlatFileRepository to a DatabaseRepository, implement the new repository, and you are finished! Everybody on the team is happy!

**Update: "Why Instantiate a Class Variable?"**

To answer that question, you have to think of your two options. The first option is that you could hold a relatively small object in memory. The other alternative is you could instantiate a new object in memory every time that a user needs to access one of your actions causing new memory to be allocated (and deallocated when you leave the scope that the object was in) and requiring more work by the server which is hosting your web app.

If you think about how a website is used, users are hitting those actions on a frequent basis. Every action signifies a portion of your website. If you instantiated every single time you needed the repository, you would quickly give the server a much bigger workload than it actually needs - particularly as your site grows in size. (I am sure other folks can think of other reasons why you would want to do it the way shown in the tutorial vs. instantiation in each individual action.)

And, then, of course, there is the refactoring issue as I mentioned above. That is about "efficiency of making changes" or improving the maintainability.

Hope that helps you a bit more and better answers your question!

Comment: Thank you for the in depth answer.  I realize that in the simple example I gave the repository was being used in the context of a controller.  However, I have seen them used in the ApplicationStart section of global.asax.  Back to the point, my main question here was to understand why a whole repository would be held, even in this controller, for so long?  It does not seem efficient to me (even if it does save a few lines of code and makes changes to the data layer connection easier) to be holding on to a repository for the entire lifespan of, in this case, a controller.

Comment: from all of the reading I have done on the repository pattern, it seems to me it is always cached beyond a single request. This does not seem best practice.

Comment: @TravisJ - Did an update. Hopefully that helps better answer your question.

Comment: @TravisJ - Are you referring to the repository pattern, or the Entity Framework (and databases in general)? That caching has nothing to do with your repository (necessarily). There are efficiencies in caching requests that are frequent. For example, if users always requests product names, but rarely request product descriptions, you may want to cache the product names results and just check occasionally to make sure you have the latest and greatest. That way, you reduce load on both your server (and database).

Comment: @TravisJ - For more information on caching (as it relates to databases in particular) read this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_caching

Comment: Thank you for the update, I understand the point about multiple requests, but did not consider that deallocating and reallocating would take up so much resources. Are there any security risks in holding(caching) objects in server memory?

Comment: @TravisJ - Not any more than what the server (IIS in the case of ASP.NET MVC) or the database (SQL Server) would allow. (It's not like the cached results are generally available to people visiting your website if you are worried about that particular situation. It's more available in the context of a particular query.)